# Error after add simple_permission or permission_handler on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a folder to try downloading files. so I added simple_permission but I got an error migrating to androidX even though I migrated to androidX. how can I resolve this error?

Launching lib\main.dart on Coolpad E502 in debug mode...

D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:9: error: cannot find symbol

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

```
                         ^
```

symbol:   class ActivityCompat

location: package android.support.v4.app

D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:10: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

```
                             ^
```

D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:156: error: cannot find symbol

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, perm, 0);

    ^
```

symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin

D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:163: error: cannot find symbol

```
    return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);

                                                ^
```

symbol:   variable ContextCompat

location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin

D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(registrar.activity(), permission)) {
                ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
D:\Flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\simple_permissions-0.1.9\android\src\main\java\com\ethras\simplepermissions\SimplePermissionsPlugin.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(registrar.context(), permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ^
  symbol:   variable ActivityCompat
  location: class SimplePermissionsPlugin
6 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':simple_permissions:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s

---

The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.\
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: I solved this with Migrate with AndroiStudio. thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old question but are you referring to Migrate to AndroidX ?

Comment: How did you solve this ? please add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and what I did was change the version of klotin in the build.gradle file I have it as follows

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```